# How to scan multiple BLE devices on iOS

Tags: swift, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, core-bluetooth

I‘m developing a swift iOS app in which I need BLE scanning between multiple devices. Suppose I have 3 devices (A, B, and C). If all three devices are in the background, each device will only scan one other device and will stop scanning after. For example, A will only scan B,  B will only scan A, and C will only scan A. After this initial background scan, no other devices will be scanned by any of the devices. However, I need A to scan both B and C, B to scan both A and C, and C to scan both A and B. I'm not sure how to approach this problem. Is there a way in which I can have an iOS device scan multiple devices in the background?

For Bluetooth peripheral and central, I used these codes from Apple's documentation:

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corebluetooth/transferring_data_between_bluetooth_low_energy_devices

Also here is my code for setting up the central manager.

```
public func centralManager(_ central: CBCentralManager, didDiscover peripheral: CBPeripheral, advertisementData: [String : Any], rssi RSSI: NSNumber) {
        //this makes it so it connects and ensures it only works if both devices have ther app
        //start sending message code
        os_log("Discovered %s at %d", String(describing: peripheral.name), RSSI.intValue)
        peripherals.append(peripheral)
        if myPeripheral != peripheral {
            
            // Save a local copy of the peripheral, so CoreBluetooth doesn't get rid of it.
            myPeripheral = peripheral
            
            // And finally, connect to the peripheral.
            print("Connecting to perhiperal %@", peripheral)
            myCentralManager.connect(peripheral, options: nil)
            
        }
        
        //end of messaging code
        
        print("\nName   : \(peripheral.name ?? "(No name)")")
        print("RSSI   : \(RSSI)")
        currentRssi = Int(truncating: RSSI)
        for ad in advertisementData {
            print("AD Data: \(ad)")
        }
        
        
    }
```

```
func centralManager(_ central: CBCentralManager, willRestoreState dict: [String : Any]) {
        print("will restore state central scene")
    }
```

```
func centralManager(_ central: CBCentralManager, didDisconnectPeripheral peripheral: CBPeripheral, error: Error?) {
        os_log("Perhiperal Disconnected")
        myPeripheral = nil
        
        // We're disconnected, so start scanning again
        if connectionIterationsComplete < defaultIterations {
            retrievePeripheral()
        } else {
            print("Connection iterations completed")
        }
    }
```

```
func centralManager(_ central: CBCentralManager, didConnect peripheral: CBPeripheral) {
        print("Peripheral Connected")
        
        // Stop scanning
        myCentralManager.stopScan()
        print("Scanning stopped")
        
        // set iteration info
        connectionIterationsComplete += 1
        writeIterationsComplete = 0
        
        // Clear the data that we may already have
        data.removeAll(keepingCapacity: false)
        
        // Make sure we get the discovery callbacks
        peripheral.delegate = self
        
        // Search only for services that match our UUID
        peripheral.discoverServices([ServiceID])
    }
```

```
func centralManager(_ central: CBCentralManager, didDisconnectPeripheral peripheral: CBPeripheral, error: Error?) {
        os_log("Perhiperal Disconnected")
        myPeripheral = nil
        
        // We're disconnected, so start scanning again
        if connectionIterationsComplete < defaultIterations {
            retrievePeripheral()
        } else {
            print("Connection iterations completed")
        }
    }
    
    private func retrievePeripheral() {
        
        let connectedPeripherals: [CBPeripheral] = (myCentralManager.retrieveConnectedPeripherals(withServices: [CovtraceID]))
        
        print("Found connected Peripherals with transfer service: %@", connectedPeripherals)
        
        if let connectedPeripheral = connectedPeripherals.last {
            print("Connecting to peripheral %@", connectedPeripheral)
            self.myPeripheral = connectedPeripheral
            myCentralManager.connect(connectedPeripheral, options: nil)
        } else {
            // We were not connected to our counterpart, so start scanning
            myCentralManager.scanForPeripherals(withServices: [CovtraceID],
                                                options: [CBCentralManagerScanOptionAllowDuplicatesKey: true])
        }
    }
```

Comment: It works fine in the foreground

Comment: Please  [edit] your question to show the relevant code.

Comment: @Paulw11 I just added some relevant code. Thanks for your help, please let me know if I should share any more info.

Comment: The discovery (CBCentral)  code is probably more relevant since you are having issues with discovery, not advertising

Comment: @Paulw11 thanks for the reply. I just updated my code that has the CBCentral function that are in my code. I hope this is more relevant.

Comment: You stop scanning in `didConnect` - which means you will only discover and connect to one peripheral.  Don't do that.

Comment: @Paulw11 I believe it works in the foreground though. I am able to connect to multiple devices in the foreground. Why would it be any different in the background? Thanks again for your help

Comment: Perhaps you are restarting scanning at some point when your app is in the foreground.  Regardless, there should be no reason to stop scanning in an application such as this.

Comment: Also, in the case where the peripheral disconnects if you want to reconnect you can just call `connect` on the peripheral that was passed to `didDisconnect`.  This statement `myPeripheral = peripheral` also concerns me - you want to handle multiple peripherals but you are storing a reference in a single property; You probably want an array or set of peripherals.

Comment: @Paulw11 thanks! I will try to find where I restart scanning and make it so I don't stop scanning anywhere.

Comment: hi @Paulw11 , I fixed my code so it doesn't stop scanning. Additionally,  I do already have an array of peripherals. You may have missed it, but I have it in the first chunk of code as " peripherals.append(peripheral) ". Additionally, I am just adding some more code that may be relevant. I am including my retreive peripheral and didDisconnect functions. They are the bottom two chunks of code. I appreaciate all your help!

Comment: Yes, you do, but you also have `myPeripheral`

Comment: @Paulw11 , thanks. I uploaded some more code on the bottom of my question. Also, our idea was that myPeripheral is the peripheral we are currently scanning for. Peripherals (which is an array) stores all the scanned peripherals from the time the application was launched. Is this approach correct?

Comment: Doing that creates a race condition; A new peripheral can be discovered at any time, overwriting `myPeripheral`.

Comment: Hi @Paulw11  . Would changing the advertisement flag to nonconncetable work? I think maybe the problem is that I can only connect to one device in the background.  I am confused on where I would implement this change and how I would go about making it nonconnectable. I only need to scan and advertise, I do not need to connect. Trying to connect to the devices might be my problem. Do you agree that this might be the issue? Also, do you know if you can send data between devices without connecting?

Comment: You can't advertise a non connectable peripheral with Core Bluetooth.  You can't "exchange" data without connecting; You can include some data in the advertising packet which could be seen without connecting. I don't see why you need `myPeripheral` - Every delegate callback includes the `CBPeripheral` that the event is referring to, so as long as you have a collection of peripherals you are dealing with it should be possible to handle multiple peripherals at one time.

Comment: Can a string that I defined be included in the data for the advertising packet?       String schoolID = 12345-986343-24141234

Comment: I don't know if you have that much room, maybe.  Also you can't advertise that data when your app is in the background on iOS

Comment: I checked this and there wasn't enough room for the advertising packet. Another idea I have is disconnecting devices from each other everytime after they connect and advertise. Do you know how this can be done in the foreground and background? This would solve all our issues. Thanks for your help. @Paulw11

Comment: You can do this, but it can be troublesome. You can look at the source code for the Australian government COVIDSafe app. This uses that approach but that app is known to disrupt other Bluetooth operations including Apple Watch connections